# Kivy ToggleButtons did not adjust according to different window sizes

Tags: python, kivy, togglebutton, stacklayout

I want my CustomLabels and CustomToggleButtons, which I have created, to change their sizes according to different Window sizes. So this was what I did.

> lbl = CustomLabel(text=text, width=self.grid_layout.width,   >height=self.grid_layout.height*.5)
>
> btn = CustomToggleButton(group=text, text=config_type[i], width=40 + >len(config_type[i]) * 20, height=self.grid_layout.height * .5)

What I did was set the above widgets' heights and widths above proportionate to a GridLayout containing them. The GridLayout's size is relative to the MainScreen. So if I change the Window size, the GridLayout would follow, followed by the widgets.

However, it did not work. Whenever I change the Window size, the CustomLabels and ToggleButtons would remain the same in size. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

This is the full code:

```
Builder.load_string('''

#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<CustomButton>
    font_size: self.width * .1
    background_color: hex('#669999')
    
<CustomToggleButton>:
    background_color: hex('#669999')
    font_size: self.height*.5
    size_hint: None, None
    # height: self.parent.parent.height * .1
    
<CustomLabel>:
    font_size: self.height * .5
    size_hint: None, None
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    # width: self.parent.parent.width
    # height: self.parent.parent.height * .1 

<CustomBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
<CustomStackLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    spacing: 10

<TempBoxLayout>:
    spacing: 10
    CustomBoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustomButton:
            text: 'Temp Up'
        CustomButton:
            text: 'Temp Down'
    Label:
        text: '20'
        font_size: self.width * .1
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: hex('#000000')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

<MainScreen>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    CustomBoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#669999')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_layout
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#000000')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .4
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_x: .25
            TempBoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_x: .25

''')


class CustomButton(Button):
    pass


class CustomToggleButton(ToggleButton):
    pass


class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass


class CustomBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class CustomStackLayout(StackLayout):
    pass


class TempBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    store = JsonStore('remote_config.json')
    power = str(store['power'][0])
    mode = str(store['modes'][0])
    fan_speed = str(store['fan_speed'][0])
    swing = str(store['swing'][0])
    louver = str(store['louver'][0])
    min_temp = store['min_temp']
    max_temp = store['max_temp']
    curr_temp = min_temp
    temp_interval = store['interval']
    config = [store['power'], store['modes'], store['fan_speed'], store['swing'], store['louver']]
    titles = ['Power', 'Mode', 'Fan', 'Swing', 'Louver']
    grid_layout = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.grid_layout.rows = 0
        print(self.power, self.mode, self.fan_speed, self.swing, self.louver)
        for i in range(len(self.config)):
            self.populate_controls(self.config[i], self.titles[i])

    def populate_controls(self, config_type, text):
        if len(config_type) is not 1:
            if config_type != 'not available':
                stack_layout = CustomStackLayout()
                self.grid_layout.rows += 1
                lbl = CustomLabel(text=text, width=self.grid_layout.width, height=self.grid_layout.height*.5)
                stack_layout.add_widget(lbl)
                for i in range(len(config_type)):
                    btn = CustomToggleButton(group=text, text=config_type[i], width=40 + len(config_type[i]) * 20,
                                          height=self.grid_layout.height   * .5)
                    if i is 0:
                        btn.state = 'down'
                    stack_layout.add_widget(btn)
                self.grid_layout.add_widget(stack_layout)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

This is the JSON file:

```
{
  "power": ["off", "on"],
  "min_temp": 18,
  "max_temp": 32,
  "interval": 1,
  "modes": ["cool", "fan", "dry"],
  "fan_speed": ["auto", "low", "med-low", "med", "med-high", "high"],
  "swing": ["off", "auto"],
  "louver": ["off", "auto"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest fix is to use `size_hint`. Try changing your `CustomLabel` and `CustomTogglebutton` definitions in your `kv` to:

```
<CustomToggleButton>:
    background_color: hex('#669999')
    font_size: self.height*.5
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.5

<CustomLabel>:
    font_size: self.height * .5
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.5
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
```

And you no longer need `width` and `height`speifications in your `Python` code for these objects. Also, change `CustomStackLayout` to:

```
<CustomStackLayout>:
    size_hint_y: 1.0
    spacing: 10
```